# How can I ask mathematica to fill in small marginal area in regionplot3d?

Tags: graphics, regions

I am stuck at how to fill in some marginal area in my regionplot3d. Here is my code.

```
RegionPlot3D[y >= -11, {x, 200, 1000}, {y, -11, -7}, {z, -11, -8}, 
 PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, \[Infinity]}, Mesh -> None, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, Axes -> {True, True, False}, LabelStyle -> 14,
  AxesLabel -> {Style["Mass", Black, Bold, FontSize -> 14], 
   Style[Rotate["Factor", \[Pi]/2], Black, Bold, FontSize -> 14], 
   None}, Ticks -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.25, Blue], 
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Thick], 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Thick], AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 450, 
 Boxed -> False, FaceGrids -> {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, -1}}]
```

Compiling the code, it gives this image.

[image]

Here, what I want to know is how can I fill in some small white space appearing between blue boundary line to its closest axis. In other words, I would like to colour the whole space by blue. Any help would be very thankful.